# Google Analytics Custom Reports with Funnel Conversion rate

Tags: google-analytics, dimensions, funnelweb

How can we add funnel conversation rate in Custom reports?

I want to add funnel conversation to custom dimensions in report.

Thanks.

Comment: Funnel is visualization only, so there is no funnel conversion rate, only goal conversion rate (which is a metric, not a dimension). Plus reporting topics should go to webmasters.stackexchange rather than here (stackoverflow is usually reserved for problems with code).

Comment: Defiantly goal conversion rate is metric which we can show with any dimensions. I have created one custom dimensions and  I want to use Funnel Conversation rate (Which usually comes under funnel visualization ) with that.